# FreeIMU_serial.ino and hmc58x3.h

Tags: c++, c, arduino

How can the problem be okay?

```
In file included from FreeIMU_serial.ino:7:
C:\Users\rouzbeh\Documents\Arduino\libraries\HMC58X3/HMC58X3.h:96: error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant
```

line 96 HMC58X3.h is:

```
void setDOR(unsigned char DOR);
```

Comment: and a little bit about `DOR` will be helpful. Looks line a previous `#define`..

Comment: Is `DOR` defined somewhere else? Possibly as a macro?